# Get User GUILD from a specific Channel with Discord.Net

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I thought I ask here on Stackoverflow. My problem is that I have tried multiple times to receive User Guilds of a specific server/channel.

My first try was to create a class:

```
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DiscordBot
{
   class AllUsersGetter : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
   {
      public IReadOnlyCollection<SocketGuildUser> Users;

      public async Task Traitement()
      {
         Users = Context.Guild.Users;
      }
   }
}
```

But it was a more stupid idea by me. I did this afterwards:

```
AllUsersGetter allUsersGetter = new AllUsersGetter();
allUsersGetter.Traitement();
var u = allUsersGetter.Users;
```

But then I got an exception that I need an object reference, that wasn't given.

```
private IList<SocketGuildUser> guidData;

public async void MainAsync() {
   string token = "";
   client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig() {
      LogLevel = LogSeverity.Verbose
   });

   DiscordRestClient = new DiscordRestClient(new DiscordRestConfig() {
      LogLevel = LogSeverity.Verbose
   });

   client.Log += Log;

   try {
      await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
      client.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
      client.Connected += Client_Connected;
      await client.StartAsync();
   } catch (Exception exc) {
      StatusLabel.Text = exc.Message;
   }
   await Task.Delay(-1);
}
```

**Conclusion:** I am clueless...

I just want to get an array of all users located inside a specific server/channel.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the users within a guild/channel with the `IGuild#GetUsersAsync`/`SocketGuild#Users` method/property.

See more information about these members on the [official Discord.Net documentation](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.html#Discord_WebSocket_SocketGuild_Users).

Furthermore, the client is not ready right after connection. Consider hooking the [Ready](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient.html#Discord_WebSocket_DiscordSocketClient_Ready) event as described in the [Managing Connections](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/concepts/connections.html#usage) article.